# Netbeans Plattform - Branding doesn't work on created installer

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I created a netbeans plattform application. I used the branding feature to add to change the window title and the splash screen of the application. If I start the application directly with the run button from the IDE the branding works. But if I create an installer for windows and install the application the branding didn't work anymore.

If I start the installed application I see the default splash screen and the application title is changed to "Netbeans Plattform Application".

It is needed to add the branding to the installer?

(I used netbeans 8.0.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same problem under Netbeans 7.4,the solution should also apply to netbeans 8 and above. 
Basically, when you are running the application from the IDE it picks up the branding from your folder structure.But, when you are running it outside the  IDE, it specifically looks for a branding parameter. When it doesn´t find one, then it provides the default branding(splash screen etc.) of netbeans. The solution is- you have to provide an extra branding parameter as a startup argument.

My project is a Netbeans Maven Project. I created an extra config file, added it inside the pom file as follows-

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>       
            <configuration>
            <etcConfFile>${basedir}/installer/my.conf</etcConfFile>
            </configuration>
   </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now inside the my.conf file simply add your branding cluster-

```
default_options=" --branding your_branding_cluster "
```

Hopefully, it helps.

Comment: I didn't use maven. But I already use a config file "projectname.conf" where I define the jdkhome and the default_userdir Could I use this config file?

How could I found out the name of the branding cluster?

Comment: Hey Markus, sorry for getting back to you so late. Anyways, yes, you can use the same projectname.conf file. Branding cluster is also known as branding token. Probably you are using ant build. You can find your branding token under project structure as  `platform.properties` as `branding.token=your_branding_token`